# node_modules when testing different dependencies in different branches

Tags: node-modules

When I have different dependencies in different branches, the node_modules folder gets messy. I usually rename the folder for the specific branch and include that folder to the .gitignore in other branches.

what's the best way to manage the node_modules folder?